# Simple Tree C++ implementation

Tags: c++, template

I've done this simple c++ assignment. The homework was "Design a Tree class that allows insertion of nodes and visit of the graph".

What do you think of the style/**design** I used? I chose to store in the STL container the pointers of sub trees.

Is it **memory** efficient?

Is it sufficiently *readable*?

Did I chose the right STL container?

Thanks a lot for any tips about problems or bad practices!

What do you think of the style/**design** I used? I chose to store in the STL container the pointers of sub trees.

Is it **memory** efficient?

Is it sufficiently *readable*?

Did I chose the right STL container?

Thanks a lot for any tips about problems or bad practices!

```
#include <set> 
#include <deque> 
#include <iostream>
  using namespace std;

template < typename T >
class Tree {

struct compare {
  bool operator()(const Tree * t1,
    const Tree * t2) const {
    return t1 -> GetContent() < t2 -> GetContent();
  }
};

typedef typename std::multiset < Tree * , typename Tree::compare > NodeSet;

private:
  NodeSet children;
T content;

public:

  Tree& AppendNode(const T& node) {
    Tree *t = new Tree(node);
    AttachTree(t);
    return *t;
  }
void Clear() {
  typename NodeSet::iterator it = children.begin();
  while (children.end() != it) {
    children.erase( *it);
    delete *it;
    it++;
  }

}
const T& GetContent() const {
  return content;
}
Tree(const T& root) {
  content = root;
}
void AttachTree(Tree* t) {
  children.insert(t);
}
void Visit(std::deque <T>& exp) const {
  exp.push_back(content);
  typename NodeSet::iterator it = children.begin();
  while (it != children.end()) {
    (*it) -> Visit(exp);
    it++;
  }
}
Tree() {}
Tree(Tree & c) {
  c.DeepCopyTo(this);
}
T & operator = (const Tree & b) {
  b.DeepCopyTo(this);
}
~Tree() {
  Clear();
}
void DeepCopyTo(Tree* dest) const {
  dest -> content = content;
  typename NodeSet::iterator it = children.begin();
  while (it != children.end()) {
    Tree* t = new Tree();
    (*it)->DeepCopyTo(t);
    dest->AttachTree(t);
    it++;
  }
}

 };
```

https://ideone.com/62Ggwu

Answer (score 3):

### Use `using` keyword to define your type instead of `typedef`

C++11 introduced type alias which can be used to define your own type and it's compatible with templates, so instead of:

```
typedef typename std::multiset < Tree * , typename Tree::compare > NodeSet;
```

you'll get this:

```
using NodeSet = std::multiset < Tree * , Tree::compare >;
```

### Consider using range-based `for` loop instead of `while` loop with iterator

I think that it will result in simplier and more readable code, for example `Visit` function will look like this:

```
void Visit(std::deque <T>& exp) const {
  exp.push_back(content);
  for (const auto& child : children)
        child->Visit(exp);
}
```

### Unnecessary `erase` call in `Clear` function

The following call:

```
children.erase( *it);
```

is unnecessary - multiset `childern` will be erased automatically.

### Reconsider memory management

Currently it's possible to add new child to existing `Tree` by calling function

```
void AttachTree(Tree* t)
```

which expects pointer to existing `Tree` object as argument. It means that `Tree` is not repsonsible for creation of children. By the other hand, in destructor the `Clear` function is called which deletes all the children, which means that `Tree` takes responsibility for deletion of children. This might lead to undefined behaviour. Consider the following code:

```
Tree<int>* t1 = new Tree<int>(1);
{
    Tree<int> t2(2);
    t2.AttachTree(t1);
    {
        Tree<int> t3(3);
        t3.AttachTree(t1);
        std::cout << "1. t1 content: " << t1->GetContent() << "\n";
    } // t3 desctructor is called, which means that t1 has been deleted
    std::cout << "2. t1 content: " << t1->GetContent() << "\n"; // t1 doesn't exist anymore - what's the result of t1->GetContent() ?
} // t2 desctructor is called and t1 will be deleted again
std::cout << "3. t1 content: " << t1->GetContent() << "\n"; // t1 doesn't exist anymore - what's the result of t1->GetContent() ?
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the review!! What's the easiest way to deal with the last issue?

Comment: What about simply rewriting attach method to force a deep copy?